# How to write loop in MySql

Tags: mysql

```
#Here I get all the ids which I want to iterate over  and will be used as value X
SELECT testcase_id FROM testcases_types where type_id = 26;


#Value X = testcase_id will be the value I want to insert
INSERT INTO `testcases_types` (`testcase_id`, `type_id`) VALUES (X, '66');
```

How can I write this in MySQL ?

Comment: I hope testcase_id is not a primary or unique key.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO testcases_types (testcase_id, type_id)
SELECT testcase_id, '66' 
    FROM testcases_types 
    WHERE type_id = 26;
```

[MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  INSERT ... SELECT Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot :)  . I never heard about this Insert...Select command. Is this available long time ??? I thought I have to use @Loop Begin ... End .

Comment: @Julia19 *Is this available long time ???* It seems it exists always...

Comment: Is this only available in MySQL or also in MySQL Server from Micorosoft ???  But you also know this Begin ... End syntax ?? What is this for ?? And what is the name for this kind of writing Begin ... End .

Comment: @Julia19 *MySQL Server from Micorosoft* - not exists. It is "SQL server". And yes - all DBMSs knows `INSERT .. SELECT` (in some of them it is the only way to insert more than one record per statement). *But you also know this Begin ... End syntax ??* Not relative to your quesion. And yes - I know about this construction.

Comment: I mean this.https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/loop.html   This way insert ... Select could also be solved. What do you think.

Comment: @Julia19 *I mean this* This can be used only in compound statement (stored procedure, function, etc.), not in single query.

Comment: Yeah. Compound Statements, that is the word I was looking for. But Insert....Select also is a compound statement in the end .

Comment: @Julia19 *Insert....Select also is a compound statement* No. From any point of view.

Comment: But it is 2 statements. Insert AND Select . But maybe the term compound statement still means something different.

Comment: @Julia19 *it is 2 statements.* Please read Reference Manual. Or at least something about SQL... This is ONE statement. Like a query with subqueries is NOT multi-statement.